# Microphone audio quality suddenly dropped, regardless of what microphone I use on my laptop

Tags: laptop, audio, microphone

So, I figure that this must be an issue with my laptop, right? I have a a Dell Inspiron 15 7000.

My microphone is part of a headset, in the headphones jack. One day, I was playing video games with my friend. Out of nowhere he says, "Your microphone is awful now. What did you do?" (I hadn't so much as moved) I changed the headset I was using, but the problem persisted. I ran an audio check by recording my own voice on my laptop and playing it back, and it was a bit off.

Anyone know why this would have happened or how I can solve it?

Answer (score -2):

Try to find something like "noise cancelation" in the audio control panel.
This can cause the problem (as you tried locally record your voice).

Easy to happen with an auto driver install from windows update.